# Jenkins Setup: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, build, perforce, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to setup jenkins in my local machine where perforce is also installed. I wanted to build my UE4 project in jenkins.

I created a user called Jenkins in perforce and gave jenkins the username following this

https://patricevignola.com/post/automation-jenkins-unreal

But when i try to build I'm getting this console output and it says "Unable to setup workspace" but the build shows success.

> 19:31:52  Started by user Jenkins
>   19:31:52  Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:52  p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:3
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:52  p4 info
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:4
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:52  p4 info
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:5
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -i
>   19:31:52  p4 client -i
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  Client jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1 not changed.
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:6
>   19:31:52  P4: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 counter change
>   19:31:52  p4 counter change
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:7
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 changes -m1 -ssubmitted //jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1/...
>   19:31:52  p4 changes -m1 -ssubmitted //jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1/...
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:8
>   19:31:52  P4: no revisions under //jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1/... using latest change: 21
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 repos -C
>   19:31:52  p4 repos -C
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:9
>   19:31:52  Building on Node: master
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:52  p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:3
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:52  p4 info
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:4
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:52  p4 info
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:5
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -i
>   19:31:52  p4 client -i
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  Client jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1 not changed.
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  (p4):stop:6
>   19:31:52  P4: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  P4 Task: establishing connection.
>   19:31:52  ... server: localhost:1666
>   19:31:52  ... node: DESKTOP-DP775O3
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:52  P4 Task: reverting all pending and shelved revisions.
>   19:31:52  (p4):cmd:... p4 revert C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...
>   19:31:52  p4 revert C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...
>   19:31:52
>   19:31:53  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/... - file(s) not opened on this client.
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:7
>   19:31:53  ... rm [abandoned files]
>   19:31:53  duration: (12ms)
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  P4 Task: cleaning workspace to match have list.
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 reconcile -w -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...
>   19:31:53  p4 reconcile -w -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/... - no file(s) to reconcile.
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:8
>   19:31:53  duration: (12ms)
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  P4 Task: syncing files at change: 21
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 sync -q C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...@21
>   19:31:53  p4 sync -q C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Abhimanyu/...@21
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:9
>   19:31:53  duration: (11ms)
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  P4 Task: saving built changes.
>   19:31:53  Found last change 21 on syncID jenkins-NODE_NAME-Abhimanyu-EXECUTOR_NUMBER
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:53  p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:3
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:53  p4 info
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:4
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:53  p4 info
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:5
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -i
>   19:31:53  p4 client -i
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  Client jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1 not changed.
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:6
>   19:31:53  P4: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:53  p4 client -o jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:3
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:53  p4 info
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:4
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 info
>   19:31:53  p4 info
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:5
>   19:31:53  (p4):cmd:... p4 client -i
>   19:31:53  p4 client -i
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  Client jenkins-master-Abhimanyu-1 not changed.
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  (p4):stop:6
>   19:31:53  P4: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   19:31:53  ... done
>   19:31:53
>   19:31:53  Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue. The NPE itself seems to be fixed with this: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/changes/24968 -> client/ClientHelper.java#121 line: 170

NPE happens when no "View Mappings" are defined, so you need to have at least one entry for "View Mappings" - example:

1. Go to "Configure" of your Jenkins project
2. Go to

   > Source Code Management -> Perforce Software -> Workspace behaviour -> View Mappings
3. Enter your perforce clients' view mapping like:

   ```
   //org/my/project/... //MyPerforceWorkspaceName_123/org/my/project
   ```

Have fun!